# Draw a straight line between starting and end points

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I have a line chart with different data points (the amount of points can be different). I am using chart.js plugin.
I need to draw a single straight line from the first point to the last.

I've attached a screenshot, where red line is what I expect to happen.

Thanks, in advance!

[image]

Comment: You could make use of chart plugin.

Comment: I am using already chart.js plugin. I mentioned it in tags.